# ES Won't Start on Win x64 Java SE 8 u 171/2

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Win 10 x64. I updated to Java 8 Update 171. Attempting to run ES up with this command line

```
cd bin

elasticsearch.bat -Ecluster.name=ABTest_Cluster_00 -Enode.name=ABTest_Node_00
```

resulted in failure to start with this rather cryptic error

```
Common was unexpected at this time
```

I upgraded to 172 and it was the same. (Disclaimer: It might have been "not expected" rather than "unexpected" but I'm not re-installing 172 to check it and then downgrading again.)

I had a look in jvm.options and the only place I could find "common" was in a comment

```
# turn off a JDK optimization that throws away stack traces for common
# exceptions because stack traces are important for debugging
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

Downgrading to je 8 U 162 fixed the issue and all was well.
My local DynamoDB ran up OK under the latest Java. Is this an issue with how I'm starting ES (don't think so - it's been working for ages)? Is an issue with ES or Java? Is there a work around that anyone knows of as I'd rather run the latest Java.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For me helped to change in elasticsearch.bat from %JAVA% to !JAVA! in line 47

Comment: Thanks, Adiu - I'll try it. May be a couple of days before I get the chance.

Comment: It turned out to be line 46 for me. Oddly the *third* time I installed update 172 it just worked anyway. But that doesn't take away from the fact that your alteration sorted it as well. BTW - what's the differenece between % & !?

Comment: Looks like this is connected with this: https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html . % works "wors" then ! for some special characters like " etc. Looks like here JAVA has some characters which breaks work of % (at least for me this was true)

Comment: Thanks, Adiu - line 46 for me also on 6.3.2

Answer (score 2):

With elastic 6.6.2

- change line 46 of elasticsearch.bat - from %JAVA% to !JAVA!
- change line 60 of elasticsearch-env.bat - from %JAVA% to !JAVA!