# Elastic Search startup error - "\Common was unexpected at this time."

Tags: elasticsearch

I have downloaded and extracted elasticsearch and when I run the batch file "elasticsearch.bat' I am getting the following error.

```
"\Common was unexpected at this time."
```

Solved:

By editing line 46 of the 'bat' file

`'%JAVA%'  ==> '!JAVA!'`

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50019539/es-wont-start-on-win-x64-java-se-8-u-171-2

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for your help.

Comment: But I couldn't understand the difference between '%' and '!'

Comment: The third comment in the solution explains it

Comment: What do you change ? `in (\`"%JAVA% -cp "!ES_CLASSPATH!" "org.elas...` ?

Answer (score 34):

I also encountered the same issue while running the batch file "elasticsearch.bat" in windows 10. 
I set JAVA_HOME using below command and it worked for me.

**set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\your_jdk_version"**

Comment: I think it depends on your version. Had the error stated by the author and now I have `could not find java; set JAVA_HOME or ensure java is in PATH` after running this command

Comment: Put your installed jdk version at the place of your_jdk_version in the command

Comment: As mentioned correctly in this answer, this happens when you try to run Kibana from Windows command line, after you install JAVA, but don't set JAVA_HOME. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I placed `SET "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191"` just under `SET params='%*'` inside `"bin\elasticsearch.bat"` and that made it work

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
setlocal enableextensions

SET params='%*'
SET "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191"

:loop
......
```

Answer (score 3):

`set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\\[your_jdk_version]"`

type this with your version of jdk above and retry running the bat file

Answer (score 2):

Remove in path variable like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` and go for it.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cannot-start-elasticsearch/129779/10

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by editing my Environment Variables - System variables - variable named CLASSPATH. The variable contained

`;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\EMC\ExJNIAPIGateway.jar`

I quoted this

`;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\EMC\ExJNIAPIGateway.jar"`

Everything ran smoothly afterwards. I don't really know what corporate software that jar file relates to, but I'm not bothered if it stops working on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

Set the java home it works. No need to edit elasticsearch.bat file
[Refer the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1K4K.png)