# How to get each string in a list of strings?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a List of String separated by a space and enclosed in double quotes.

```
"D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin" "C:\ORACLE_HOME\bin" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\" "C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\" "C:\WINDOWS\system32" "C:\WINDOWS" "C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem" "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\" "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL" "C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT" "C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT" "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin" "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\" "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\" "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\hello\tasm\lib" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin" "C:\MinGW\bin" "C:\src\flutter\bin" ""D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin" "C:\ORACLE_HOME\bin" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\" "C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\" "C:\WINDOW"" "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools" "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin" "C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\condabin" ""
```

I want to get each one of them using a for loop in batch file.

I was trying to debug an batch file from another software (since it crashed because of the space between `\Common Files\`)

rmpath.cmd (Code)

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if  _%1==_ goto USAGE
set fqElement=%~fs1
set fpath="%PATH:;=" "%"
echo %fpath%
for %%p in (%fpath%) do (
  set p2=%%~fsp
  if /i NOT "!p2!"=="%fqElement%" (
    if _!tpath!==_ (set tpath=%%~p) else (set tpath=!tpath!;%%~p)
  )
set path=!tpath!
ENDLOCAL & set path=%tpath%
```

Comment: You know to use a `for` loop, but what have you tried? You're very close already.

Comment: Or may be you can do that with `split()` function..!?..like..`string.split(" ")`..I may be wrong..just give it a try..!

Comment: Does `cmd` support split?

Comment: @SomethingDark I used to write batch files a long time ago...Tried doing random things, didn't work out

Comment: I notice that near the end, you have `""D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin"` instead of `"D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin"`, which is throwing some things off.

Comment: `\Common was unexpected at this time` this is the error I get...

Comment: `\Program Files (x86)\` doesn't throw an error, but the other one does...strange

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131300/elastic-search-startup-error-common-was-unexpected-at-this-time

Comment: Seems like the input list of paths already contains quoted items, which cause the troubles here. You could try to double quotation marks like `set "fpath=%PATH:"=""%"` (then `set fpath="%fpath:;=" "%"`) and undo that eventually like `set "PATH=!tpath:""="!"`. Anyway, to check for emptiness use `if "%~1"==""`...

Comment: My testing shows that your issue is solely caused by the double quote I mentioned earlier. Get rid of it.